# Data class dynamically change serializable name

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I just started my internship and I am asked to some basic implementations with Retrofit, etc. I have a Json response which has a key value that changes according the request parameter and I don't know how to get the value of that key.

**Like this :**

```
{
  "status": {
    /*Some other unimportant JSON here */
  },
  "data": {
    "KEY_THAT_CHANGES": {
      "id": 74,
      /* more JSON here */
    }
  }
}
```

I guess there are multiple solutions to get that key: by index (because it is always the first key inside "data") or by passing the serializable name as the parameter (because I already have the key) or use a custom deserialize class.

**Request functions :** the key in the Json and the symbol parameter, are the same

```
@Headers(API_KEY)
    @GET("v1/cryptocurrency/info")
    fun getCoin(@Query("symbol")symbol: String):Call<CoinInfo>
```

**I have the following Data Classes to hold data :**

```
data class CoinInfo(
    val `data`: Data,
    val status: Status
)


data class Status(
    val credit_count: Int,
    val elapsed: Int,
    val error_code: Int,
    val error_message: Any,
    val notice: Any,
    val timestamp: String
)


data class Data(
    val Coin: Coin //Here is the problem, the key is dynamically changing
)


data class Coin(
    val category: String,
    val date_added: String,
    val description: String,
    val id: Int,
    val is_hidden: Int,
    val logo: String,
    val name: String,
    val notice: String,
    val platform: Any,
    val slug: String,
    val subreddit: String,
    val symbol: String,
    @SerializedName("tag-groups")
    val tag_groups: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("tag-names")
    val tag_names: List<String>,
    val tags: List<String>,
    val twitter_username: String,
    val urls: Urls
)
```

**Request call**

```
val api = Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .build()
             .create(getRequest::class.java)

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
     val response = api.getCoin(coin.symbol).awaitResponse() // coin.symbol is also the key of the JSON
         
            if(response.isSuccessful){
                val data = response.body()!!

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    // TO DO
                }
            }
        }
```

I couldn't find any helpful solution and I just started to learn Kotlin about 36 hours ago.

Comment: Consider using `java.util.Map`.

Comment: Example, please @terrorrussia-keeps-killing

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your api delivers either `Coin` or `Bill`, then you might model it like this:

```
data class Data(
    val Coin: Coin?,
    val bill: Bill?
)
```

If i remember correctly, gson will just set missing keys to null, so you can check later on what was actually delivered.
This is a acceptable solution when you have a known amount of objects witch differ substantially from each other.

---

If your coin-objects don't differ structurally or you have an infinite amount of names, then you most probably should change your api and do sth. similar to this:

```
data class Coin(
    val myCoinIdentifier: String, /* 1-ct-coin, 2-ct-coin, 5-ct-coin...  */
    ...
)
```

---

A word about style:

- calling a class `Data` is discouraged, as it's the most generic description you can give. Also, `data` might be a reserved one, see `data class`. Instead, use actually useful names
- variable names should start with a lower case letter, to differentiate them from the class they represent, e.g. use `val coin: Coin`, not `val Coin: Coin`
- we don't use underscores in variable names, go with camel casing, e.g. `tagGroups`, not `tag_groups`
- you should have a good reason to send `any` over a network, can't you specify that further?
- <s>you shouldn't need the single ticks around `'data'`</s>

Comment: I just had a chance to talk to my internship master about this and he agreed that it is an exceptional case and easiest solution is to write a function who would parse the JSON manually. I suppose this is not something that happens all the times when using API's.

But thanks for the tip about 'Data', I normally do not use that cuz using such a word as a variable name is enough scary. It is something the JSON to Data Class generator wrote but going to change it. Thanks.